# In oracle, how can i convert character data in a column that falls under [a-z][A-Z] to some random char x

Tags: sql, regex, oracle11g

In oracle 11g, how can I convert character data in a column that falls under `[a-z][A-Z]` to some random char x. For example: if my source column data is tom then I should get xxx and if my source column data is lilly then I should get xxxxx.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Would be good to now what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(name_of_source_column, '[a-zA-Z]', 'x')
  AS source_column_with_letters_replaced_by_x
```

(except, of course, that `source_column_with_letters_replaced_by_x` is not a valid identifier in Oracle).

Comment: Hi, I was thinking on similar lines but did not get the syntax correct.  Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT dbms_random.string( 'A', length( <<input string>> ))
  FROM dual
```

will return a random, mixed-case string of alphabetic characters that is as long as `<<input string>>`.  I think that's what you are looking for.  I'm not clear from your question, however, whether you only want to replace alphabetic characters in the source string.  That is, if the input string was "Tom4Jerry", would you want the output to be "xxx4xxxxx" where x is a random character?  Or would you want "xxxxxxxxx"?

Comment: Hello Justin, I have a requirement where I need to mask first name, last name of the users. So, I thought of converting the characters to x. Your suggestion to use dbms_random.string is a real good idea for masking. Thanks a lot for the information.